# How do I detect taps in the gesture area on the Palm Pre?

Tags: webos, palm-pre

Playing with my Palm Pre phone. I want to detect the user tapping in the gesture area (the area directly below the screen). How do I do that?

I haven't found anything obvious in the framework API's or service API's.

Answer (score 3):

The gesture area is treated as the `metaKey` modifier on tap and key events. Listen for `Mojo.Event.tap` anywhere on the page, rest your finger on the gesture area, and then tap where you are listening. The event should have `event.metaKey` set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this page, which describes capturing gesture-area inputs using the SDL_PollEvent method in the Plug-in Development Kit (PDK):

http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1980&Itemid=337#GestureAreaInput

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to use the PDK yet...

Answer (score 1):

You can check mojo-keydown and -keyup - code 57575.  Try the APIs sample, Input, Key Presses section.